# NetBeans 6.9 Ruby Gems Manager

Tags: ruby, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I am using NetBeans 6.9 for my Ruby On Rails Applications. I have a problem with ruby gem manager. I can't access to new gem. The error is: Gems fetching failed. Follows output of the gem tool:
ERROR: while executing gem... (Errno::ENOENT).
Nu such file or directory. C:/Users/{username}.

I got the same problem(cyrylics user name) when I try to install gems from console. And this problem was solved by changing gem.bat like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET _HOMEDRIVE=%HOMEDRIVE%
SET _HOMEPATH=%HOMEPATH%
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
SET HOMEPATH=/WebServers/usr/local/Ruby/bin/
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/WebServers/usr/local/Ruby/bin/gem" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
SET HOMEDRIVE=%_HOMEDRIVE%
SET HOMEPATH=%_HOMEPATH%@ECHO OFF
SET _HOMEDRIVE=%HOMEDRIVE%
SET _HOMEPATH=%HOMEPATH%
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
SET HOMEPATH=/WebServers/usr/local/Ruby/bin/
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/WebServers/usr/local/Ruby/bin/gem" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
SET HOMEDRIVE=%_HOMEDRIVE%
SET HOMEPATH=%_HOMEPATH%
```

But why this problem stay in IDE...